# Does maven compiler plugin with source 1.6 configuration recognise API introduced since 1.7?

Tags: java, maven, javac

I've a maven project with the maven-compiler-plugin configured as below:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

In my code I use a class java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets which is introduced since 1.7.
I'm surprised that my code compiles successfully, shouldn't the plugin throw an error because java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets is not 1.6 compilant?

Comment: Even though you tell the compiler to compile bytecode for 1.6, the rt.jar which is uses will still be the 1.7 rt.jar; this is why you can use classes which are defined in there.

Comment: @fge rt represents runtime right? I thought there should be a compile-time error thrown before runtime since StandardCharsets is not 1.6 source

Comment: Well, unfortunately no there won't be. Your best guardian here is really your IDE: it should be able to correctly infer that you try and use classes from a JDK version which is not the target version your project is supposed to be compiled with. At least IDEA does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `target` nor `source` relate in any way to what classes are available on the compiler's classpath.  If you're compiling your code with the 1.7 compiler then any classes that shipped with 1.7 will be available to your code.

What `target` does is tell the compiler to output .class files in a format that is compatible with the 1.6 release of java.  `source` says only accept java code that would compile with the 1.6 version of the compiler.

So it's perfectly legitimate to make a call to a class that shipped only on 1.7 or later using Java 1.6 compatible source code written into a class file that is compatible with Java 1.6.  It just won't run on 1.6.

The only way to ensure your code will run on 1.6 (if that's what you're trying to do) is to use a 1.6 JDK to compile your project.

Comment: Another way to ensure that it runs with 1.6 is by using the animal sniffer maven plugin (http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/).

Comment: @JJF but I set the target flag to 1.6, will the 1.7 compiler be smart enough to compile the 1.7 API into some 1.6 compliant bytecode so it will run on 1.6 JVM?